# Select a counterexample to show that the given statement is false, or state that there is no counter example or we wouldn't use a counter example.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, examples-counterexamples

Conjecture: If $a$ and $b$ are two integers such that $\frac ab$, then $\frac ba$.

a. $a = 2, b = 2$

b. $a = 2, b = 4$

c. There is no counter- example.

d. We would not use a counter example in this case.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please don't just ask us to do your homework for you.

Comment: im confused on whats its asking.. i believe the counter example is B but im not positive about it.

Comment: Why do you think B is the counterexample? (You're right, but why do you think that?)

Comment: because when you do  2|4 = .5 and its not consider an integer.

Comment: I think you mean $2\over 4$; "$2\vert 4$" is the statement "$2$ is a factor of $4$," which is true. Now, what does the fact that ${2\over 4}$ is not an integer, have to do with the problem?

Comment: I wasn't sure what it was asking.

Comment: Well, do you understand how the fact that ${2\over 4}$ isn't an integer means that B is a counterexample?

Comment: Yes I understand that part.

Comment: Great, so you've answered the question!

Answer (score 2):

The following is the answer: 
b. a = 2, b = 4